# How to display a string in a dialogs edit box from a UI Thread Classes Run() function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ui-thread

I have a Dialog-based Application. By default Visual Studio created an App and a Dlg class.  I have added buttons, edit boxes, etc. to my dialog.  When the user clicks the START button on my dialog it runs a 5 minute automated test  and gives text updates and progress in an edit box.  Now that this is working great, I would like the user to be able to click on other buttons and check boxes in the dialog while the automated test is running.  In order to do this I created a UI thread class using the class wizard called CMyThread.  In CMyThread I moved the code that was executed when pressing the START button to the Run() function in CMyThread.  I plan on calling the CMyThread Run() function when the START button is clicked.  I would still like to get the progress and updates in the dialogs edit box while the 5 minute automated test is running.  How do I send a string from CMyThread Run() to the edit box in the dialog and have it display to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by having the MyThread class send messages to be processed by the dialog's message loop.

There are other similar questions on SO with useful answers.  [How to inform a CDialog Object about a finished task from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497674/how-to-inform-a-cdialog-object-about-a-finished-task-from-another-thread)

And here's an article with sample code http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?312454-MFC-Thread-How-to-access-UI-elements-from-a-thread-in-MFC

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I scrapped the UI thread and tried a worker thread instead.